# Не получается подключиться к Telegram Python (telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, socks5, mtproto

Скрипт выполняет поиск в определенных чатах сообщение по шаблону и вставку их в таблицу, таблица выгружается в Save messages. Не мог подключиться, Думал дело в отсутствии прокси, написал генератор(всё работало номрально).В один помент перестало подключаться любым образом. В чём может быть проблема? Может быть такое, что мне закрыли доступ из-за того что много запросов с разных прокси?(писал программу 1,5 дня без остановок)

```
proxy = dev.get_rand_proxy(dev.get_proxy_list())  # (socks.SOCKS5, '162.243.108.129', 1080)
client = TelegramClient(config.username.lower(),
                    config.api_id,
                    config.api_hash,
                    # connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate,
                    proxy=proxy
                    )
client.start() # ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)
#...код программы...
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Запустите VPN на ПК и проверьте ещё раз. Ваш вопрос к Telegram относится косвенно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема, не подключался и выводил сообщения **ConnectionError**

1.Пользуюсь сейчас VPN сервисом, соединение теперь устанавливает

2.Отключил двухфакторная аутентификация на аккаунте